No Return on API JSON, Want to Display a Text
I am using an API from Aeris Weather Alerts and when there is no alerts for the area, the response is blank ("response": []).  Using the code below, is there a code I can use when the response is blank to have a default text that reads "No Weather Alerts"?
window.onload = () => {
const target = document.getElementById('alerts');
const aeris = new AerisWeather('CODE', 'PASSWORD');
const request = aeris.api().endpoint('alerts').place('SDZ047').filter('county').limit(3);
request.get().then((result) => {
    const reports = result.data;
    if (reports.length > 0) {
      let html = '';
      reports.forEach((details) => {
        html += `
<div class="cardalert">
<div class="cardalert-body" style="background-color:#${details.details.color || '000000'};">
<div class="alertmessage">
<p><img class="iconalert" src="${details.details.color || 'N/A'}.gif"></p>
<p class="textalert">${details.details.name || ''}<br><span>Issued: ${aeris.utils.dates.format(new Date(details.timestamps.issued * 1000), 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a')} - Expires: ${aeris.utils.dates.format(new Date(details.timestamps.expires * 1000), 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a')}</span></font>
</div>
</div>
<br><p class="bodytext">${details.details.body}</p><br>
</div>
`;
      });
      target.innerHTML = html;
    }
  });
};

</script>

Nothing at this time besides putting a second layer with a text.

Yes, add an else block to your if and set the text there.

You can use an early return to check if the response is an empty array and return the HTML element
request.get().then((result) => {
    let html;
    if(result.data.length < 1) {
     html += <add your HTML response>
    return target.innerHTML = html;  // if you don't `return` here, the rest of the code will execute after this `if` condition is satisfied, which is what you want to avoid. 
    }
    const reports = result.data;


Why if(result.data.length < 1)? Do you expect an array with length -2 or 0.35? Why do you use the variable html? The downvote is for html += <add your HTML response>. It's a bug.

An array will never have a negative or partial length so using < 1 is similar to using == 0.
What is the bug?  It's exactly the same as the original question

No, it's not. Print html and you will see it. Please test your code before you post an answer. Why do you use < 1 if you actually mean == 0?

Jeremy, this worked out great.  Thank you.

@tater feel free to mark it as the answer.  You're welcome.
